# Issue installing React on Windows 10 with npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm

I'm working on a windows machine with node and npm installed. Trying to work on a React app and cannot install react using:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

error:

```
 npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
 npm ERR! errno -5
 npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-11T17_56_06_899Z-debug.log
```

Comment: posting that log file information could be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running npm cache clear --force, as a serious note only run it with --force if you know what you're doing.